# What is the best way to declare mutex and mutex.synchronize shortcut?

Tags: ruby, singleton, mutex

I am using mutex in my ruby code across many files. to deal with that I created a singleton class with one mutex object that I use all the time:

```
class LockBlock
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @lock = Mutex.new
  end

  def lock
    @lock
  end
end
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this the best way to declare my mutex object? Should I use a module instead of Singleton? I use it in many files..
2. If I use it this way, each time I lock a block, I need to write:

`LockBlock.instance.lock.synchronize {
      # code here..
}`

Is there a shortcut for this? maybe to declare the lock function so I will be able to write something like this:

```
LockBlock.lock {
  # code here..
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you may be interested in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was not familiar with that. Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LockBlock` is itself an object, which can be used to store the `@lock` instance, and it's a singleton across the whole application.

You may use it for a global singleton lock:

```
class LockBlock
  @lock = Mutex.new
  class << self
    Mutex.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
      define_method(method) do |&block|
        @lock.send(method, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end

# Now LockBlock is a Mutex like singleton object 
# and you can use it anywhere in your application (load when necessary)

LockBlock.lock
begin
  puts LockBlock.owned?
ensure
  LockBlock.unlock
end
LockBlock.synchronize { puts LockBlock.owned? }
```

IMO the singleton pattern is more used in Java like static OO language, not that useful in dynamic language.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't like the Singleton way too, I just wasn't sure how to do it better.. I am kinda new to Ruby and mutex.. I have one more question: what is the purpose behind the code you wrote before the synchronize? (the lock and begin block..)?

Comment: @Guy That's a common pattern to use a lock. It ensures that the lock will be released regardless of the code status (ie. exception throwed?) between the `begin...ensure` part. `synchronize` is just a shortcut for that.